# Can an Edit Text in android allows the user not to edit its first line

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm really new to android and my first project is to create a diary.
and my problem now is that I want the users to input text to an edit text that shows the 
Dear diary, already. But I want that line to be not editable. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set non-editable text in an edit text field while allowing editable text below it.. The purpose of an edit text is to edit the text as the name suggests. Disabling the edit text after setting initial text to "dear diary" will disable the edit text all together, and I don't think that's what you want. For your sake I would put a text view above the edit text that says "Dear Diary..." or whatever you'd like it to say, then go from there. After the diary entry has been completed, if you want it to start with "Dear diary.." you could append the body of the diary entry to the "Dear Diary.." string like so:

```
String header = "Dear Diary... ";
String body = editText.getText();
String finalEntry = header+body;
```

.. or something of that nature. Hope this helps!

Comment: hmm so its impossible haha. but if I do the text view above my edit text once the user inputs many characters that will allow the text to scroll up the dear diary would not scroll up it will just stay there looking awkward

Comment: @Anthony Nievera Jr - If you put both the TextView header and the EditText body in a single linear layout, then put that LinearLayout in a ScrollView, both should scroll together. You may have to play around with how you have things laid out, but that should do the trick if you want both to scroll? That might give you the effect you're looking for... but it might not haha. Give it a try!

Comment: yeah I was thinking about that XD I will try it sir thanks for your suggestions

Comment: so I did try that but my problem is when the edit text is filled it scroll up by itself its not resizing hmm any suggestion?

Comment: I did it already XD my bad I put the wrong code hahah Thanks for this

Comment: @Anthony Nievera Jr - Glad I could help! You should mark the question as "Answered" :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this after creating the editText

editText.setString("Dear Diary");

editText.setEnabled(false);

or simply use a TextView and set the Text:

textView.setText("Dear Diary");

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a TextView above the edittext that says dear diary. Then when you are handling the string from the EditText you can append Dear diary to the beginning.

Comment: thanks for that but would the Text View scroll up too?
and what do you mean by appending it at the beginning ?? sorry for really noob questions -_-

Comment: RyanM shows what I mean by append it. As for the scroll up you'll have to elaborate on what you're looking for. But you should be able to manipulate the TextView into doing something close to what you're looking for